# Send mail with multiple file attachments using HttpFileCollection without saving it first

Tags: asp.net, email, sendmail

I want to send email with multiple file attachment.

I use `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage`, and add all file attachments in `HttpFileCollection`.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
string body = BodyTextBox.Text;
string smtpServer = "mail.MySite.com";
string userName = "info@Mysite.com";
string password = "***";
int cdoBasic = 1;
int cdoSendUsingPort = 2;
if (userName.Length > 0)
 {
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver", smtpServer);
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", 25);
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", cdoSendUsingPort);
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", cdoBasic);
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", userName);
   msg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", password);
  }
 msg.To = "doc@Mysite.com";
 msg.From = "info@Mysite.com";
 msg.Subject = "Sent mail";
 msg.Body = body;
 if (fileUpload.HasFile)
  {
   int iUploadedCnt = 0;
   HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
   for (int i = 0; i <= hfc.Count - 1; i++)    // CHECK THE FILE COUNT.
    {
     HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
     if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
      {
       hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploaded_Files\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
       msg.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath("Uploaded_Files\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)));
       }
     }
    }

   msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = smtpServer;
   SmtpMail.Send(msg);
```

It is ok, But i don't want to save file in server, I want send a mail without saving it.

Comment: is the email being sent from client or from server? Or do you mean you're ok with sending attachments to the server, but you don't want them to be saved?

Comment: Yes,send from server, but i don't want to save file.  'hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploaded_Files\\") + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));'. I want to add attachment file whiout save it in server.

Comment: you can make a temporary save in your application and after sending file you make that file delete from you application.

Comment: I use it, but i don't save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` class, instead of the `System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment` class, and you can use the overload that accepts a `Stream` as the first argument:

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
 if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
 {       
   msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(hpf.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName)));
 }
```